# How can I export the 'result' returned from a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to use node js to place MySql data eventually in an HTML( really an ejs) page.

I have been using the code below from W3's node js examples. https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp

What I eventually would like to do is use module.exports on 'result', and be able to access the array in another file. I have been finding this difficult to accomplish.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({ 
    host: "localhost",
    user: "username", 
    password: "password", 
    database: "testdb" 
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    console.log(result); 
});

// This is what is logged to the console.

// [ RowDataPacket { name: 'Company Inc', address: 'Highway 37' }, 
  RowDataPacket { name: 'Sanitation', address: 'Highway 27' }, 
  RowDataPacket { name: 'Ice Cream', address: 'Highway 11' } ]

// Above works but it doesn't do what I need it to. 
// Below is explained what I need to happen.

var mysql = require('mysql');

var x; // x is undefined

var con = mysql.createConnection({ 
    host: "localhost", 
    user: "username", 
    password: "password", 
    database: "testdb" 
});

con.connect(function(err) { 
    if (err) throw err; 
    con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", 
    function (err, result, fields) { 
    if (err) throw err; 
    x = result; // If I do a 'console.log(x);' here I get the array above. 
    // If try to 'module.exports = result;' here, it is 
    // undefined in the receiving file. }); 
});

console.log(x); // x is undefined, even though result was stored in x.
```

I would expect for the 'console.log(x);' at the bottom of the code to return the array, but it is undefined. This makes me think that anything in the 'con.query' is local. If that is the case, I considered using 'module. exports = result' in the function, but that also returns an undefined variable in the receiving file. If anyone knows why this happens, or if there is a solution, I would be very appreciative of your advice : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you need to do is export your function, and use it whenever you want

What I suggest is that you export the database connection variable, so you can use it whenever you want, something like:

config.js

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({ 
    host: "localhost", 
    user: "username", 
    password: "password", 
    database: "testdb" 
});
exports.default = con
```

fileThatUsesResult.js

```
const db = ./config.js
db.con.connect(function(err) { 
    if (err) throw err; 
    con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", 
    function (err, result, fields) { 
    if (err) throw err; 
    //here you use your results, maybe res.json or whatever you want to do
});
```

This way you can split your code and call the dabatase connection object whenever you need it. Remember the DRY principle.

By the way, I recommend you use promise instead of callbacks functions, that way you can manage your asynchronous calls

Hope I helped!

Comment: I appreciate your help! I wasn't familiar with promises, but after looking into them, I think that is the way that I should go!

Comment: Good! If it helped mark it as answered please @LoganLuedtke

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work! The problem was that my query was an async function, and I was expecting to get my data as if I were coding synchronously. Thank you for Cesar for your suggestion to use Promises, as that was what fixed my problem. Below is the now working code.

connection.js, also as suggested by Cesar.

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "username",
      password: "password",
      database: "testdb"
    });

    module.exports = con;
```

The query.js page, now wrapped in a promise;

```
    var con = require('./connection.js');

    module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        con.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
              resolve(result);
          });
        });
    });
```

app.js, which when accessed at port 3000, renders display.ejs with the db data

```
    var dataMod = require('./query.js');
    var express = require('express');

    var app = express();

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.get('/', function(request, response){

      dataMod.then(function(data){
          response.render('display', {data: data});
      });

    });

    app.listen(3000);
```

And the simple display.ejs page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <p> <%= data[0].name %> <%= data[0].address %></p>
        <p> <%= data[1].name %> <%= data[1].address %></p>
        <p> <%= data[2].name %> <%= data[2].address %></p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Which displays

Company Inc Highway 37

City Snitary Highway 27

Curbside treats middle of nowhere

on the browser!

This is just an example and is knowingly hard coded. What is the most important part, though, is the link from a database to browser using a promise. Thanks Cesar!